# Questions about dojo/dijit/dojox

Tags: javascript, mobile, combobox, dojo, dijit.form

I'm learning `dojo` to develop a simple application to be used from mobile clients. I see some widgets have different features between `dojox/mobile/*` and `dijit/form/*`. For example the `ComboBox` from `dijit` has a property to select which field of a `Memory` store use (`searchAttrb`) while the one from `dojox` hasn't:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/ComboBox.html

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox.html

1. first question: would you recommend the use of `dijit` widgets for an application that will be used from smartphones?
2. I know what `dojo/domReady!` means. But I'm not sure if I have to use it also in nested requires. Example:

   ```
   require(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/json", "dojo/domReady!"], function (xhr, JSON) {
       xhr("api/dummy", {
           handleAs: "json"
       }).then(function (data) {
           require(["dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function (Memory, ComboBox) {
               var mystore = new Memory({
                   data: data
               });

               var comboBox = new ComboBox({
                   id: "idCombo",
                   name: "blabla",
                   store: mystore,
                   searchAttr: "field"
               }, "idCombo").startup();
           });    
       }, function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       });
   });
   ```

This snippet retreives a file on the server and create the `Memory` store. Then uses the field "field" to populate the `ComboBox`. Does the inner `dojo/domReady!` is required? I guess no, because that code is reached only after the outer function has been executed.

3. I see a lot of `dojo` examples written in different manner. Some declare all the require items just after the `dojo` include. Others require only the items the functions need, function by function. What are the differences?

Examples

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4/dojox/mobile/tests/test_FormControls.html?theme=Custom

declares all the items together, and without a function associated, so no names for the items:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "dojox/mobile",
        "dojox/mobile/parser",
        "dojox/mobile/compat",
        "dojox/mobile/Button",
        "dojox/mobile/CheckBox",
        "dojox/mobile/ComboBox",
        "dojox/mobile/RadioButton",
        "dojox/mobile/Slider",
        "dojox/mobile/TextBox",
        "dojox/mobile/SearchBox",
        "dojox/mobile/ExpandingTextArea",
        "dojox/mobile/ToggleButton"
    ]);
```

while here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/checkboxes/demo/CheckBox.html

the require instruction is followed by a function:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: 1, async: 1, parseOnLoad: 1"></script>
<script>                
    require(["dijit/form/CheckBox", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"], function(CheckBox, parser) {
```

Of course they should have different meaning and use cases, but I'm not sure to understand which.

Comment: Hey Mark I have been using Dojo for the best part of a year now I would be happy to answer points 2 and 3, your first part I'm not sure about since I haven't done any mobile development

Comment: You're welcome! We will wait for some other contribution then!

Comment: @Mark for question 3 could you please post some lines with some examples? I would be glad to try to answer that question too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 01

`dojox/mobile/*` provides widgets that can be used to build web-based applications for mobile devices.

Widget in `dojox/mobile/*` are designed to be as lightweight as possible with special attention for mobile experience.

Many dependencies could be excluded when building for mobile using `dojox/mobile/*` as they are less dependent with dojo base.

I would suggest to use these widgets if your target low-end devices as using `dijit` more suite desktop application.

For question 02

`dojo/domReady!` it is not required in the inner `require`.

For question 03:

In dojo you can declare widgets in two ways, declarativelly or programmatically.

With a declarative approach you initiate widgets within your HTML and use `dojo/parser` to hook the JavaScript behavior offered by the framework.

Please note the data attribute in the HTML `data-dojo-type`

Example:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">
    <span>Click Me!</span>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/dojo/dojo.js"
    data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(parser){
        parser.parse();
    });
</script>
```

With a programmatic approach you use entirely JS, and add in the HTML only a "placeholder" where the widget will be hooked/created.

Please note that there is NO data attribute `data-dojo-type` in the HTML.

Example:

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, dom){
    // Create a button programmatically:
    var myButton = new Button({
        label: "Click me!",
        onClick: function(){
            // Do something:
            dom.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
        }
    }, "progButtonNode").startup();
});
<button id="progButtonNode" type="button"></button>
<div id="result1"></div>
```

In my personal experience I saw several times the usage of a declarative approach fitting simple widgets scenario mainly created at backed in the HTML, with "spiced" HTML added by server side script.
For a more complex SPA JavaScript application a more programmatic approach.

Comment: Found by myself: it depends if you're using the *programmatic* or *delarative* style. Here the documentation: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declarative/index.html

Comment: @Mark I just edit my answer, I hope you found useful, happy coding with dojo :)

Answer (score 3):

Seen as has GibboK covered 1 and 2 i'll go for 3!

Just before I start there are lots of different ways of working with the dojo libraries and I'm honestly not sure there is a wrong way.

I have played around with different structures and it really just depends on what you are doing most of the applications I have worked on there is an emphasis on code reuse so I tend to only define what I need for that script.

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "dojox/mobile",
        "dojox/mobile/parser",
        "dojox/mobile/compat",
        "dojox/mobile/Button",
        "dojox/mobile/CheckBox",
        "dojox/mobile/ComboBox",
        "dojox/mobile/RadioButton",
        "dojox/mobile/Slider",
        "dojox/mobile/TextBox",
        "dojox/mobile/SearchBox",
        "dojox/mobile/ExpandingTextArea",
        "dojox/mobile/ToggleButton"
    ]);
```

I tend to pull in my modules independently and pass round any global objects, i also use [`dojo/_base/declare`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html#dojo-base-declare) any custom modules I would use a [`dojoConfig`](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_config/) and reference the scripts as packages.

```
var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        { name: "my", location: "../my" },
        { name: "package2", location: "/js/package2" }
    ]
};
```

So I would start by defining a person object with a constructor as an example it takes in 2 values.

```js
// in "my/Person.js"
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang"],
  function(declare, lang) {
    return new declare("person", null, {
      fistName: null,
      lastName: null,

      constructor: function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
      },
      getFullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + " "
        this.lastName;
      },
      changeLastName: function(lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

I would then using the dojoConfig referencing the folder `../my` and create a new person object passing in the 2 values

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "my/person"],
      function(declare, person) {
        return declare("admin", null, {
          person: null,

          constructor: function() {
            this.person = new person("Jon","Doe");
          },
          fullName: function() {
            console.log(this.person.getFullName);
          },
        });
  });
```

I'm not sure if that answers all of your questions this will help

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you spent for this answer! I think the key is your first point: "there are lots of different ways of working with the dojo libraries and I'm honestly not sure there is a wrong way". My confusion is due to this "flexibility" that I still need to fully understand.

Comment: I like to add a plus to this answer, thanks for mentioning by name on your answer :)

Comment: Not problem @GibboK :) and yeah I totally understand dojo have great documentation I really recommend reading the tutorials! http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/